# how to write query with proper sorting

Tags: python, pandas

I have an issue writing query to pandas. I have a dataframe: `(item_name, order_id, quantity, item_price1)`.

The task is to get the quantity sold of most expensive product.
When I write the query like this:

```
df.groupby('item_name')['item_price1','quantity'].agg(['max','count'])
```

it works fine. But when I try to sort the result of the query to find the most expensive one using *sort_values* like this:

```
df.groupby('item_name')['item_price1','quantity'].agg(['max','count']).sort_values(by='max', ascending=False).head(10)
```

it ends with the error:

> Key error 'max'

What will be the right thing to do?

Comment: Have you tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53964251/pandas-dataframe-raises-keyerror-when-sort-values-method-is-called ?

Comment: Have you created a new `df` with a column called `max`? Can you confirm this?

Comment: No, I have not. "max" in this case is an aggregate function

Comment: Since you've got multiple columns with multiple aggregation operations then you're going to have a multi-level columns index... you need to be more specific as to which of the "max"s you want to sort on

Comment: So you probably want: `.sort_values(by=('item_price1', 'max'), ascending=False)` ?

Comment: That's the right answer, I tested.Thanks a lot, Jon.

Comment: @КонстантинОгрызко Glad to hear that - I've moved that to an answer... it might be useful for someone else and also offered an alternative...

Answer (score 0):

Moving my comments to answer:

When you do something like:

```
agg = df.groupby('item_name')['item_price1','quantity'].agg(['max','count'])
```

You end up building a multi-level column index, in this case (`agg.columns`), is:

```
MultiIndex([('item_price1',   'max'),
            ('item_price1', 'count'),
            (   'quantity',   'max'),
            (   'quantity', 'count')],
           )
```

To then use that for sorting, you need to use the specific level, eg:

```
agg.sort_values(by=('item_price1', 'max'), ascending=False)
```

On a side note - you're using `.head(10)` there to limit the total output after *fully* sorting the data, but it might be better to use `.nlargest` if your sample size is small compared to the population, eg:

```
agg.nlargest(10, ('item_price1', 'max'))
```